# ¿Como limpio el cache de una aplicacion Android por codigo?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación android sobre un catalogo, las imágenes las cargo con Glide, pero hay un problema, y es que las imágenes las pueden actualizar desde un admin de una pagina web, y cuando la actualizo en la aplicación, me sigue apareciendo la imagen anterior.

Limpie la memoria cache de la aplicación y si actualizó la imagen, pero quisiera saber la manera de eliminar el chace por código, espero sus respuestas de como hacerlo, o tavez otra solución de como refrescar las imágenes http en Glide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Usando [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) puedes evitar el caché  usando la propiedad,  `skipMemoryCache(true)`** :

```
Glide.with(Contexto).load(urlImagen).skipMemoryCache(true).into(imageView);
```

Lo que realiza esta propiedad es deshabilitar el caché.

**También usando [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), puedes evitar el caché en las imágenes agregando una firma diferente cada vez que cargues la imagen usando la clase [UUID](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html)**:

```
Glide.with(Contexto).load(urlImagen).signature(new StringSignature(UUID.randomUUID().toString())).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Segun un [issue en su github](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/624), cuando cargues la imagen tienes que especificarl la `asignature` siempre con valores diferentes para evitar que te *cachee* la imagen como por ejemplo la ultima fecha de actualizacion de perfil o la fecha actual como milisegundos:

```
Glide.with(ActividadActualOContexto.this)
     .load(urlImagen)
     .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
     .into(referenciaImageView);
```

Comment: Excelente, me sirvio pero lo raro es que no me funciono en la version 4, me funciono en la version 3, o ¿algo he hecho mal?...