# No se muestra la segunda imagen ingresada android Studio - java

Tags: java, android-studio, android-volley, android-glide, image-view

Al cargar mis imágenes de la base de datos traigo la url y la pongo en Glide, cuando elimino esa imagen y cargo con otra imagen (la cual tiene la misma url que la anterior), luego presiono el botón atrás y vuelvo a ingresar a la actividad aparece la primera imagen, solo me carga la segunda imagen cuando destruyo la aplicación y la vuelvo a cargar.
Nota: Para traer url de la base de datos uso Volley, la imagen debe tener la misma url que la primera.

cerrando la actividad y abriéndola de nuevo tampoco me funciona:

```
               finish();
               startActivity(getIntent());
```

Intente con el siguiente código para el botón atrás pero tampoco me funciono, no se que otra forma podría lograrlo, tambien intente

```
public static void trimCache(Context context) {
            try {
                File dir = context.getCacheDir();
                if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
                    deleteDire(dir);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

public static boolean deleteDire(File dir) {
            if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
                String[] children = dir.list();
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                    if (!success) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return dir.delete();
        }
```

Comment: Como cargas la imagen usando Glide?

Comment: Glide
                .with(Activity.this)
                .load(R.drawable.imagen_vacia)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.imagen_vacia)
                .into(img_view);

Answer (score 1):

Esto se debe a el caché de Glide ya que la imagen tiene la misma url, en este caso se aconseja que antes de intentar agregar una nueva imagen se debe eliminar la imagen del contenedor en este caso el `ImageView`:

```
myImageView.setImageBitmap(null);
```

---

Puedes definir al usar Glide, una politica para no guardar cache, usando> `.skipMemoryCache(true)` ejemplo

```
Glide.with(Contexto).load(urlImagen).skipMemoryCache(true).into(imageView);
```

o agregando una firma diferente por cada imagen, revisa mi ejemplo en esta respuesta

[¿Como limpio el cache de una aplicacion Android por codigo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/134693/95)

Comment: intente ponerlo en cada accion pero aun asi myImageView.setImageBitmap(null) me sigue saliendo la imagen anterior.

Comment: A que te refieres con "la cual tiene la misma url que la anterior" a que es la misma url en la misma vista pero la imagen es diiferente?

Comment: si exacto, solo el mapa de bit seria lo distinto, pero no se como podría solucionarlo

Comment: El problema al parecer es el mismo Glide, agregue dos formas en las cuales evitarias la imagen se quede en Cache, comentame resultados Josue.